# Why is my SELECT using a CTE suddenly very slow, while the CTE query itself performs well?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, query-performance

Using SQL Server 2008: I have a `SELECT` that uses a `CTE` to get pages of data. The query in the `CTE` is pretty complex -- lots of joins, unions, subqueries -- but how it's used is pretty simple: it's just using `ROW_NUMBER()` to get a page of data at a time.

The column that `ROW_NUMBER()` looks to for ordering is variable.

Up until about 24 hours ago, this query worked fine. Overnight, something happened that made the query take 50 times longer. BUT, only when the `ROW_NUMBER() ORDER BY` column is not a primary key of one of the joined tables (could be a red herring?).

The really strange thing is, the query in the `CTE` itself performs well. It's only when the outer `SELECT` that uses the `CTE` is executed that the slowdown occurs.

This query is very slow (2:30 according to SSMS):

```
WITH items AS 
( 
   SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY InventoryItems.mfg) as rownumber,
      [more columns...] 
   FROM 
      [tables, joins, subqueries] 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM items 
WHERE rownumber BETWEEN 1 AND 100 
ORDER BY rownumber
```

This query is fast (under 0:02 in SSMS. `InventoryItems.item` is the primary key for that table):

```
WITH items AS 
( 
    SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY InventoryItems.item) AS rownumber,
       [more columns...] 
    FROM 
       [tables, joins, subqueries] 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM items 
WHERE rownumber BETWEEN 1 AND 100 
ORDER BY rownumber
```

And, even though this query returns many more rows, it is fast (0:04 in SSMS):

```
SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY InventoryItems.mfg) as rownumber,
   [more columns...] 
FROM [tables, joins, subqueries]
```

Why would the CTE itself be fast, while the `SELECT` that reads it is dog slow?

Comment: What is the bottleneck according to the execution plan?

Comment: The reasons are either 1) parameter-sniffing, a SQL Server problem that can be caused by how parameters are used/invoked, or 2) the optimizer is wrong, which happens, but is rare.  As for "*why now*", likely caused by changes in the tables, keys, indexes and/or amount of data in the tables.  If what you really want is a fix, then we'll need to see the actual query plans, at a minimum.

Comment: Does 4 seconds in SSMS mean when it starts returning rows, or when it finishes?

Comment: Andrew:When it finishes.

Comment: As Tab said execution plan may help. RBarryYoung suggestions are good also. An "update statistics" may resolve the issue but I prefer that you check the original issue before using my suggestion.

Comment: What version of Sql Server are you on? Sql Server 2012 adds a new OFFSET/FETCH feature that could greatly simplify this for you, and fix your peformance issue.

Comment: Also, what happens if you just add `ORDER BY InventoryItems.mfg` to the end of the fast (0:04s) sample, or if you wrap that last sample in a CTE without WHERE/ORDER BY clauses?

Comment: Sounds like a bad execution plan.  You could try running the query with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` [query hint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714\(v=sql.100\).aspx). However, this will update the query plan used for the query, so be sure to run it exactly as the query normally would be run.  Also, you don't want to use this often because forcing a recompile every time isn't particularly good for performance.

Comment: The execution plan is at http://pastebin.com/gKYqtBcJ

Comment: The query in your execution plan is VASTLY different from the incredibly simple query you posted here. You have nonSARGable predicates in your where clause. Can you post the full query?

Comment: The question is not, "why is this query slow".  It's "Why would the CTE itself be fast, while the SELECT that reads it is dog slow?"